# How can I run code withous the 'Page' object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to send some data to the browser. In webforms obviously you can use `Response.Write();`

Is there any way I can do this if I don't have an aspx Default webform? Say I wanted to send the string `"<p>Hello World</p>"` to the browser without a webform, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net, you can register a Http Handler derived from [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) in web.config.

You might also consider switching to ASP.Net MVC, where Pages are replaced by Controllers and Views.

Answer (score 0):

Look at ASP.NET Web API, it is built for data APIs without pages.